# In laravel how to use if /else in controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I am trying to pass value from view to controller, but it not working it was sent only "APPROVED"

**my  view**

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="colFormLabelLg" class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 control-label control-label-lg"><b>DIGITAL SIGNATURE</b></label>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div  class="form-group" id=digital_signature > 
      <select  class="form-control" name="digital_signature" value="{{ old('digital_signature') }}" required autofocus  >
        <option value=""></option>
        <option style="color:green">WITH DIGITAL SIGNATURE</option>
        <option style="color:green">WITHOUT DIGITAL SIGNATURE</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**my controller**

```
public function new_approvel_update(Request $request, $id)
{  
    if($request->digital_signature == 'WITH DIGITAL SIGNATURE')
    {
          $input= Student::Where('delete_status','NOT DELETED')->find($id);
          $input['center_approved'] = strtoupper ('APPROVED');
          $input['date_of_join'] = $request->date_of_join;   
    } elseif($request->digital_signature == 'WITHOUT DIGITAL SIGNATURE') {     
          $input= Student::Where('delete_status','NOT DELETED')->find($id);
          $input['center_approved'] = strtoupper ('NOT-APPROVED');
          $input['date_of_join'] = $request->date_of_join;
    }

  $certificate->save();

  return redirect('new_application')->with('success',' APPLICATION APPROVED SUCCESSFULLY .');
}
```

Comment: The `APPLICATION APPROVED SUCCESSFULLY` is the only response in your controller function...

Comment: I doubt this code does anything but redirect with the message. (And I'm sure it doesn't even do that but give an error that `$certificate` is not defined) You're getting `$input` and setting new values, but are not saving `$input` anywhere. Just checked your code and your `if`/`elseif` is working fine the way it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `option` tag of `select` you haven't use `value` attribute. so it will pass null to a controller.

Change option tags as below :

```
<option value="APPROVED" style="color:green">WITH DIGITAL SIGNATURE</option>
<option value="NOT-APPROVED" style="color:green">WITHOUT DIGITAL SIGNATURE</option>
```

Change in your controller :

```
if($request->digital_signature == 'APPROVED'){
 // your code
}
elseif($request->digital_signature == 'NOT-APPROVED'){
// your code
}
```

Comment: "_In option tag of select you haven't use value attribute. so it will pass null to a controller._" That is not true though, if the `value` attribute of an `<option>` is omitted, the value is taken from the text content of the option element.

Comment: @kerbholz, so what was an issue in code than? why it works after given value

Comment: I have no clue, should ask OP ;) Just tested OPs code, using `dd($request->digital_signature)`, getting `"WITH DIGITAL SIGNATURE"`/`"WITHOUT DIGITAL SIGNATURE"` as result and also getting correct output using OPs `if`/`elseif` logic.